# Ticino river kayaking

Tags: italy, rivers, canoeing-and-kayaking

Since there is a drought in Italy, many rivers run at very low water.
Is there any reliable source of information concerning the water levels for rivers in Italy, especially the Ticino river?
Was someone at the Ticino river lately and can say something about the water level?

Comment: Would this question fit better at [Outdoors.SE]?

Comment: Also, what part of the Ticino river?  It starts as a small mountain stream on the Nufenenpass, then turns into a small river which may allow for some wild whitewater rafting, before becoming a rather calm and perhaps boring canalised river in the Pianura Padana.

Comment: @gerrit The Italien parts of the Ticino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a database](https://dahiti.dgfi.tum.de/en/virtual_stations/europe/italy/) with river levels across the world (derived from satellite data), but unfortunately the Ticino river is not in that dataset.

There is also [this site](https://ticino.laghi.net/) that publishes water levels of basins along the Ticino river:
[image]

Unfortunately I can't read Italian, so not sure if this is actually useful.

Finally I found [this floodalarm site](https://www.pegelalarm.eu/en/river.php?river=Ticino) that publishes the water level at different places along a water body:

[image]

Perhaps this is helpful, depending on where on the Ticino river you want to kayak.

Best would be to contact a local kayaking/rafting tour company, they will be able to tell you the most accurate situation.

Comment: The problem with this sort of data is that without a reference to compare it against, you have no idea if it's runnable.  Apart from anything else, what does a negative depth even mean?  It must refer to some (arbitrary) datum.

Comment: Absolutely agree! I just gathered some data sources I could find (as that is what the OP was asking). I'm not saying that this is *the* answer to the question and doesn't need any further interpretation. The Italian page also has [historical data](https://ticino.laghi.net/homepage.aspx?tab=3&subtab=2&idlago=3), perhaps that helps give it more context?

Comment: What do those negative water levels mean? Are they relative to a reference level?

Comment: @ChrisH-UK https://www.weather.gov/ctp/NegativeRiverStages

Comment: @Detached, yes an arbitrary (or historical) datum, which is of no practical use to a kayaker

Comment: @FedericoPoloni see the link Detached posted